# Problems with Mexico visa document (SAE) for Ukrainian citizen with U.S. student visa

Tags: visas, paperwork, mexico, ukrainian-citizens

[image]
<sup>http://www.inm.gob.mx/index.php/page/Solicitud_de_Autorizacion_Electronica/en.html</sup>

I am planning to travel to Cancun, Mexico.  I am a Ukrainian citizen with a U.S. student visa. I am having great difficulty submitting this form, as it will not allow me to enter the date of arrival. I have tried calling Mexican consulates with no luck.

Comment: Have you tried entering it in the format they requested?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm afraid we can't do much on Travel.SE. We're a Q/A site and in no way affiliated with the mexican customs and border agency. You should try contacting them directly.

Comment: "it will no[t] allow me to enter...": how is it preventing you from doing so? What happens when you try?

Comment: yes I have entered it in the correct format, which is the same format as the rest of the document, trust me I have tried a million different ways to enter that date and none work, no matter which date I enter it tells me "intented date of arrival is not a valid date" - it is the only thing preventing me from submitting the form, I am happy to send you a screen shot if you like , also thanks for replying so quickly!

Comment: Attach a screenshot.

Comment: Okay I added the screenshot at the top with my question

Comment: It won't let you enter a date more than 30 days in advance

Comment: @Berwyn I think that should be an answer, not a comment, as it answers the OP's question.

Comment: yep looks like you figured it out, THANK YOU !!

Comment: I am immediatly nominating this to be reopened. It is VERY much about travel, and is not a problem one would need to talk to Mex. Customs and Immigration about. There is an answer, and it is an issue which another could face. IOW, there is no valid reason for this to be on hold/closed.

Comment: I agree it is about travel. BTW, authorisation is correct spelling!

Comment: Since you have a US visa, you do not need a Mexican visa or electronic authorization to visit Mexico.

Comment: @Berwyn heh, I'll bet you spell the words favour and colour as well? :p

Comment: @CGCampbell sure do!

Comment: @user102008 That is a valid response here as well, perhaps you might add an answer pointing it out?

Answer (score 13):

According to this page: http://visasmex.com/files/SAE_eng.pdf an electronic authorisation is valid for 30 days from date of issue. Hence it seems you cannot apply for this authorisation more than 30 days in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a valid US visa, [you do not need a Mexican visa or electronic authorization to visit Mexico](https://mexico.visahq.com/requirements/Ukraine/resident-United_States/).

> Starting May 1st, 2010, all foreigners, regardless of their nationality, visiting Mexico as tourists, transmigrate or for business matters will not need a visa for Mexico as long as they hold a valid US visa and arrive in Mexico from the United States.